# How do I submit a form without page reload using Ajax

Tags: python, json, django, ajax

I'm learning Ajax on how I can submit a comment form without page reload. I'm using Django, I have list of posts in homepage each with comment form. When I submit a comment it is not saving in database and also it doesn't display in browser. When I check on Chrome console, I got an error 2 elements with non-unique id.

[image]

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def home(request):
    all_images = Post.objects.filter(poster_profile=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_comment")
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment=form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user=request.user
            comment.commented_image=post_obj
            comment.save()
    else:
        form=CommentForm()
context = {'all_images':all_images, 'form':form}
if request.is_ajax():
    html=render_to_string('ajax_feeds_comment.html', context, request=request) 
return render(request, 'home.html', context)

#home.html
{% for post in all_images %}
<img src="{{ post.image.url }}">
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
<p>{{ comment.comment_post }}</p>
{% endfor %}
<div class="reload-form">
{% include "ajax_feeds_comments.html" %}
</div>
{% endfor %}

#ajax_feeds_comments.html
<form method="POST" class="feeds-comment" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" value="{{post.id}}" name="post_comment">
<textarea name="comment_post" class="form-control" id="id_comment_post{{post.id}}"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).on('submit', '.feeds-comment', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
console.log($(this).serialize());
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: $(this).attr('action'), 
    data: $(this).serialize(), 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(response){
        $('.reload-form').html(response['form']);
   }, 
    error: function(rs, e) {
        console.log(rs,responseText);
   }, 
   });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things not correct here:

1. In your "urls.py" you should not send every request to your views. This is where you get the "favico.ico" error 500 get from. Having no favico is ok, but getting a Error 500 is not.
2. Check the html code for duplicate id's! These have to be unique.
3. If you use django variables for html, do it like this: Instead of "{{post.id}}" use: "{{ post.id }}" with spaces around the var.
4. In the

   document.on("submit", "feeds-comment", function(){...})

   you're not using the id of that element but it's class name.
5. Check where the submit is going to. Check Django if the request is being handled. (You see that in the console where Django is running). Also maybe Post a screenshot here!

Comment: @gxor...i was able to solve favicon problem, no 500 internal server error in console. I added {{ post.id }} to form id, same problem still occurs

Comment: @gxor....how do I solve this problem, I followed your instructions and still same problem.

Comment: Do you get anything in the "if request.method == 'POST':" branch? Can you check this? (simply print something). Else it is probably not sending the request. Check your browser developer tools (hit F12) and go to "network analytics" to see if something appears.

Comment: @gxor...when I submit my first comment and checked console I got my comment and id printed out. But when I submit a second comment I got an error in chrome console "undefined"

Comment: @gxor..I have two post in my homepage, when I submit a comment I get an error 2 elements with non-unique id, if I have three post in homepage I get an error 3 elements with non-unique id. Even when I added {{ post.id }} in textarea

Comment: @gxor...i was able to get those error removed, but I have a problem now. If I submit my form using Ajax, my comment do not display, it looks like it's hidden. Until I refresh my browser then my comment appears. And also I found out that, if I use related_name to get comment display {% for comment in post.comments.all %} it doesn't, but if I use a query in views.py (Comments.objects.all()) my comment display. This is confusing to me. How can I make a query for comment to each post in views.py? Is that possible without using related_name directly in template?